# nrwl nx angular Can't resolve 'child_process'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, nrwl

*I'm using https://nx.dev/angular to develop a microservice app but now I'm getting the following errors:*

```
ERROR in /home/vagrant/document-registry/node_modules/@graphql-tools/git-loader/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/vagrant/document-registry/node_modules/@graphql-tools/git-loader'
```

*This particular subproject is an Angular app and I don't know how to prevent node modules that are not part of the browser API from being packaged since the entire application is being used with one `package.json` file. I'm running this in a vagrant environment.*

*Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?*

Comment: Hello How did you solve this issue?

Comment: You have to make sure you're not including dependencies from NestJS modules or using creating shared libs for NestJS and Angular. Split them out.